How to parse a what looks like a combined xml file?
I have an app that creates an xml file. It looks like 3 xml files combined into one? I want to parse the file but when opening it with elementtree it shows an error "junk after document element: line 67". How could I go about parsing this file?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<episodedetails>
    <title>Put a Ring On It</title>
    <showtitle>Tom and Jerry in New York</showtitle>
    <uniqueid type="tmdb" default="true">3020993</uniqueid>
    <uniqueid type="tvdb">8009040</uniqueid>
    <userrating>0</userrating>
    <top250>0</top250>
    <season>1</season>
    <episode>1</episode>
    <plot>Tom and Jerry storm a department store after dark.</plot>
    <mpaa>TV-PG</mpaa>
    <playcount>0</playcount>
    <lastplayed></lastplayed>
    <aired>2021-07-01</aired>
    <studio>HBO Max</studio>
    <credits>Will Finn</credits>
    <thumb>https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/4xCFkRNWdbVdepDCQkqiXVODCk2.jpg</thumb>
</episodedetails>

<episodedetails>
    <title>Come Fly with Me</title>
    <showtitle>Tom and Jerry in New York</showtitle>
    <uniqueid type="tmdb" default="true">3052622</uniqueid>
    <uniqueid type="tvdb">8519098</uniqueid>
    <userrating>0</userrating>
    <top250>0</top250>
    <season>1</season>
    <episode>2</episode>
    <plot>Jerry befriends a pigeon.</plot>
    <mpaa>TV-PG</mpaa>
    <playcount>0</playcount>
    <lastplayed></lastplayed>
    <aired>2021-07-01</aired>
    <studio>HBO Max</studio>
    <credits>Will Finn</credits>
</episodedetails>

<episodedetails>
    <title>Bubble Gum Crisis</title>
    <showtitle>Tom and Jerry in New York</showtitle>
    <uniqueid type="tmdb" default="true">3052623</uniqueid>
    <uniqueid type="tvdb">8519099</uniqueid>
    <userrating>0</userrating>
    <top250>0</top250>
    <season>1</season>
    <episode>3</episode>
    <plot>Tom and Jerry battle for a bag of gumballs.</plot>
    <mpaa>TV-PG</mpaa>
    <playcount>0</playcount>
    <lastplayed></lastplayed>
    <aired>2021-07-01</aired>
    <studio>HBO Max</studio>
    <credits>Will Finn</credits>
</episodedetails>


Your XML is malformed, which means it's invalid. You have no root node.

It's unfortunate that it says standalone="yes"; without that it would be a well-formed XML entity (a fragment rather than a document), which some parsers can handle. Perhaps parsers that handle XML fragments will cope with this even with the inappropriate header.
